# Creación de columnas en python con condiciones

Tags: python

Estoy intentando hacer esto en python,pero no se como hacerlo. Primero crear la columna cve_beneficio que asigna una clave dependiendo del CVE_TIPO_FLUJO que tengan por ejemplo cve_beneficio=01 si la CVE_TIPO_FLUJO es 7, lo que quiero que ponga en la columna beneficio, es cuando en registro tengo el mismo para varias filas (ejemplo 399) coloque en la columna la cve de beneficio con monto mayor, por ejemplo vemos como a 399 le asigna en beneficio 05 porque 2861958 es el monto mayor. Agradeciera mucho su ayuda [image: resultado esperado en python]

Answer (score 2):

La pregunta es muy confusa. Si entendí correctamente, lo que pides es que la columna "beneficio" reciba el valor de la columna "cve_beneficio" correspondiente a la fila que tenga el valor máximo de entre todas las filas que tienen un mismo "Registro".

Al menos eso es lo que has explicado antes del ejemplo, y lo que muestra el ejemplo como resultado. Sin embargo en la pregunta mencionas que la columna "CVE_TIPO_FLUJO" tenga 7, pero en realidad el valor de esa columna no parece pintar nada en el ejemplo, así que ignoraré esa frase.

Por tanto lo que necesitas es:

1. Agrupar el dataframe por la columna "Registro", para que así todas las filas que tengan un mismo valor en esa columna queden juntas en un "mini-dataframe" que después se podría procesar.
2. Mediante .apply() aplicar una función (que debemos escribir) a todos los "mini-dataframes" que salgan de la agrupación anterior.

Es esa función a escribir la que se tiene que ocupar de:

1. Localizar el elemento máximo en la columna "MONTO", y en concreto el índice (fila) en que aparece, para extraer de esa fila el valor de la columna "cve_beneficio"
2. Asignar a la columna "beneficio" el valor obtenido en 1 (eso lo asignará a todas las filas del "mini-dataframe"
3. Retornar el mini-dataframe resultante

Enseguida pongo el código, pero antes, para comprobar que funcione, crearé un dataframe como el que mostraste en la figura, pero mediante código para que cualquiera lo pueda copiar y pegar para comprobar el funcionamiento:

```py
data = """
cve_beneficio   Registro   CVE_TIPO_FLUJO      MONTO
          01          13                7    3918347
          02         399                1      92764
          03         399               17    2572226
          04         399               13      11288
          05         399                5    2861958
          01         152                7    3851813
          04         152               13    3625610
"""
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data), sep=r"\s\s+", header=0)
# Añadimos la columna "beneficio", inicialmente con todo ceros
df.insert(0, "beneficio", 0)
print(df)
```

Sale:

```
   beneficio  cve_beneficio  Registro  CVE_TIPO_FLUJO    MONTO
0          0              1        13               7  3918347
1          0              2       399               1    92764
2          0              3       399              17  2572226
3          0              4       399              13    11288
4          0              5       399               5  2861958
5          0              1       152               7  3851813
6          0              4       152              13  3625610
```

y ahora la

### Solución

```py
def get_cve_max(g):
  clave = g.loc[g.MONTO.idxmax()].cve_beneficio
  g.beneficio = clave
  return g

df = df.groupby("Registro").apply(get_cve_max)
print(df)
```

y el resultado es

---

```
   beneficio  cve_beneficio  Registro  CVE_TIPO_FLUJO    MONTO
0          1              1        13               7  3918347
1          5              2       399               1    92764
2          5              3       399              17  2572226
3          5              4       399              13    11288
4          5              5       399               5  2861958
5          1              1       152               7  3851813
6          1              4       152              13  3625610
```

Comment: Hola! gracias por tu respuesta, solo que yo tengo un dataframe bastante grande, y me lanza el siguiente error: initial_value must be str or None, not DataFrame, intente covertir a tpo string para ocupar la función que mencionas pero sigue apareciendo eso

Comment: No se si te entiendo, pero mi respuesta es sólo lo que aparece tras "solución". El código previo es tan solo para crear la variable df a la que aplicar la solución. En tu caso esa variable ya la tenías, no necesitas lo de read_table(). O no era este el problema?

Comment: si era, muchas gracias!